# "My.Computer.Clipboard" object in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Does anyone know how to use  "My.Computer.Clipboard" object in Excel. I have tried almost all references by going to tools->References. i want to use code like

```
If My.Computer.Clipboard.ContainsImage() Then
      Dim grabpicture As System.Drawing.Image
      grabpicture = My.Computer.Clipboard.GetImage()
      picturebox1.Image = grabpicture
End If
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/computer-resources/storing-data-to-and-reading-from-the-clipboard

Thanks

Comment: You seem to be looking at vb.net code but you might want to be looking at MSForms.DataObjects for it to work in Excel - try http://excel-macro.tutorialhorizon.com/vba-excel-putting-text-in-the-windows-clipboard/

Comment: thanks @jamheadart

Answer (score -1):

In a Module , place this code (or in the same module than your test code):

```
Option Explicit

#If Win64 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
#Else
    Public Declare Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
#End If
```

Than , you can do your test by the following code.

```
If IsClipboardFormatAvailable(2) <> 0 Or IsClipboardFormatAvailable(14) <> 0 Then ...
```

Note: 14 is for metafile, 2 is for bitmap.

Note 2: This works in 64 bit and 32 bit Excel.

Note3 : for looking if text is present : `if IsClipboardFormatAvailable(1)<>0 then ...`

For getting the data (image) from clipboard to an Image control (in a userform, i guess), use `Me.Image1.Picture = PastePicture` , you can find its code by Google-ing "ModPastePicture" also, since this is not a method proper to vba. It is a lot faster than saving picture to disk + reloading it in the control image.